# Looping through a list of tuples in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a sample `List` as below

```
List[(String, Object)]
```

How can I loop through this list using `for`?

I want to do something like

```
for(str <- strlist)
```

but for the 2d list above. What would be placeholder for `str`?

Comment: You can loop over the strings in a `List[(String, Object)]` with `for (str <- list.map(_._1))` or `for ((str, _) <- list)`.

Comment: It's not a "2d" list. It's one-dimensional list, each of the elements being a pair. So what do yo mean by "loop through"? Get each pair in turn, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest using map, filter,fold or foreach(whatever suits your need) rather than iterating over a collection using loop.

Edit 1:
e.g
 if you want to apply some func foo(tuple) on each element

```
val newList=oldList.map(tuple=>foo(tuple))
val tupleStrings=tupleList.map(tuple=>tuple._1) //in your situation
```

if you want to filter according to some boolean condition

```
val newList=oldList.filter(tuple=>someCondition(tuple))
```

or simply if you want to print your List

```
oldList.foreach(tuple=>println(tuple)) //assuming tuple is printable
```

you can find example and similar functions here 
https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html

Comment: nice suggestion, but you could have left an example and get a vote.

Comment: added few examples

Comment: Thank you map was something I was looking for.

Comment: Another reference with more examples,
https://alvinalexander.com/scala/iterating-scala-lists-foreach-for-comprehension/

Answer (score 14):

Here it is,

```
scala> val fruits: List[(Int, String)] = List((1, "apple"), (2, "orange"))
fruits: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,apple), (2,orange))

scala>

scala> fruits.foreach {
     |   case (id, name) => {
     |     println(s"$id is $name")
     |   }
     | }

1 is apple
2 is orange
```

Note: The expected type requires a one-argument function accepting a 2-Tuple.
      Consider a pattern matching anonymous function, `{ case (id, name) =>  ... }`

Easy to copy code:

```
val fruits: List[(Int, String)] = List((1, "apple"), (2, "orange"))

fruits.foreach {
  case (id, name) => {
    println(s"$id is $name")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `for` you can extract the elements of the tuple,

```
for ( (s,o) <- list ) yield f(s,o)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the strings you could map over your list of tuples like this:

```
// Just some example object
case class MyObj(i: Int = 0)

// Create a list of tuples like you have
val tuples = Seq(("a", new MyObj), ("b", new MyObj), ("c", new MyObj))

// Get the strings from the tuples
val strings = tuples.map(_._1)   

// Output: Seq[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

> Note: Tuple members are accessed using the underscore notation (which
>   is indexed from 1, not 0)